# How Data Delete row from database with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, connection

Here is my php code

> AjaxServer.php

```
include '../include/connection.php';

//here check the prediction 

if(isset($_POST["delete_me"]) && $_POST["delete_me"]=="true"){

    $id = $_POST["id"];

    $table = $_POST["table"];

    $query = "delete from {$table} where id='{".$id."}'";

    if(mysql_query($query)){

      echo "record has been deleted";

    }

}
```

This is my js file Custom.js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.delete').click(function(e) {

        if(confirm("Do you realy want to delete this")){

            e.preventDefault();

            var parent = $(this).parents("tr");

            var table = $(this).attr("data-table");

            var id = $(this).attr("id");

            var data ="id="+id+"&delete_me=true&table="+table;

            $.ajax({

                type: 'post',

                url:'include/ajaxserver.php',

                data: data,

                beforeSend: function() {

                    parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
                },
                success: function() {

                    parent.slideUp(500,function() {parent.remove();});
                }
            });

        }
        else{

         return false;

         }

    });/*end of the cick function*/

});/*end of the ready function*/
```

Comment: You're begging for SQL injections with that. And a variable table-name that can be controlled by the client is quite unsafe. Do you get any errors, in the console or in your PHP log?

Comment: What is happening when you click your delete button? Are you getting any console logs? Is your web server giving any php errors?

Answer (score 0):

you are not sending your data to ajax file correctly replace you ajax code by following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url:'include/ajaxserver.php',
  data: {id: id, delete_me: true, table :table},
  beforeSend: function() {
  parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
  },
  success: function() {
  parent.slideUp(500,function() {parent.remove();});
 }
});
```

Hope this code will help.